# Rename goaccess.io tag

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Could you please rename [goaccess.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goaccess.io) tag to [goaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goaccess) in SO. The former is the website, the program is the latter.

Answer (score 2):

Since there were only 12 questions tagged with it, I manually edited each question and created the tag excerpt with the existing content.

[goaccess.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goaccess.io) should go away when the cleanup process runs.